# Python Tkinter color not working, it is the same whether I change the customization with canvas

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I apologize in advance for any ignorant mistakes I make, I am still a beginner.

I recently started using tkinter on python, and while I tried using the backround customization in tkinter, It does not change any colors in the backround, the same goes with the frame. below is the code I have written.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk

class GUI:
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(
        height=700,
        width=700,
        bg="#263D42"
    )
    canvas.config(bg="green")
    canvas.pack()
    root.mainloop()

    frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
    frame.place(relheight=0.8, relwidth=0.8)
```

I am using M1 MacOS if that information helps, here is a screenshot of the GUI, it is the same when I comment out the color customization in the code.  [image: Here is the screenshot of the GUI]

Comment: Are  you aware that those last two lines won't run until the window has been destroyed?

Comment: When I run this code on my OSX box, the canvas appears green, though it's not based on the M1 chip.

Comment: Yes I am aware that the last two lines won't run, however the issue is that the window will not change color, I am assuming it has to do something with the objects being created within the window but I cannot find anything in the internet for that and I am left in the dark.

Comment: I can confirm that this code works on Linux, too (it shows a green window on my Ubuntu 20.04). Assuming that the code we see here is the code you're running, it's a probably platform-specific (and perhaps platform version-specific) issue.